# How to delete items from pl. file by using retract

Tags: prolog

```
retract(byCar(auckland,hamilton)).
retract(byCar(hamilton,raglan)).
retract(byCar(valmont,saarbruecken)).
retract(byCar(valmont,metz)).
retract(byTrain(metz,frankfurt)).
retract(byTrain(saarbruecken,frankfurt)).
retract(byTrain(metz,paris)).
retract(byTrain(saarbruecken,paris)).
retract(byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok)).
retract(byPlane(frankfurt,singapore)).
retract(byPlane(paris,losAngeles)).
retract(byPlane(bangkok,auckland)).
retract(byPlane(losAngeles,auckland)).
```

i had key in the above things with my items in pl file.
but the prolog shows predicate protected. 
what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use dynamic predicates. To use them, you need to declare them as dynamic:

```
:- dynamic(byCar/2).
:- dynamic(byTrain/2).
:- dynamic(byPlane/2).
```

Then to retract, you can do them *en masse* if you wish, or individually:

```
retract(byCar(auckland,hamilton)).
retract(byCar(hamilton,raglan)).
retract(byCar(valmont,saarbruecken)).
retract(byCar(valmont,metz)).
```

Or to retract all of the `byCar` clauses:

```
retract(byCar(_,_)).
```

You may also just retract, for example, the ones from `valmont`:

```
retract(byCar(valmont,_)).
```

Note that this just retracts the facts from memory and doesn't delete them from the original file. To delete from the file, you have to rewrite the file after retracting the facts you wish to exclude. See predicates such as `telling/1`, `tell/1`, and `told/0` (for Edinburgh-style I/O).